# How to solve error "You have specified an invalid column ordinal"

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

Why I'm not getting the values of the column "nome_pizza"?

This is my code:

```
try
            {
                MySqlConnection objconect = new MySqlConnection("DATABASE=pizzaria ; port=3306 ; SERVER=localhost ; UID=root ; pwd='' ");

                objconect.Open();

                MySqlCommand objcmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT nome_pizza FROM pedidos ORDER BY id_pedido ASC", objconect);

                MySqlDataReader reader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    textBox1.Text = reader.GetString(0);
                    textBox1.Text = reader.GetString(1);
                    textBox3.Text = reader.GetString(2);
                    textBox4.Text = reader.GetString(3);
                    textBox5.Text = reader.GetString(4);
                }
```

I tried so many times but it still appearing this error message:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T77w4.png)

The textbox1 is getting the right value, but when it turns to textbox2 the error message appears

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Might get better response if posted to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting only 1 column in your SELECT query, but trying to fetch too many column values after your read, `reader.GetString(1)` will start giving you the error.
If you want to set the value of the column `nome_pizza` to *all* the text boxes, then initialize all of them to reader.GetString(0) only. Or, were you missing to select few other columns and missed in your SELECT query, then mention those column names in your SELECT query.

Comment: But I'm trying to get like all the values of the collum "nome_pizza" in order, this command is working in a DataGridView, but I need to make it work in TextBoxes

Comment: I think you are not understanding, each time you call `reader.Read()` , only 1 record will be returned and that 1 record will have only 1 value.  Show us your table structure and what data values you want to retrieve from it and fill to your text boxes, you may need to edit your question and add more details.

Comment: Sorry, I copied my code wrong, look there now.
I wanted to get all values of "nome_pizza" ordered by id_pedido

Comment: Even now your code is just querying a table without any filters, just getting 1 column value ordered by another column. That query result and what you are trying to do is out of order - you need to first understand how SQL query results are handled using ADO.NET. Read this to learn how to use [`ExecuteReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader)

Comment: hmm but you know how can I get the values of a collum ordered that way??

Comment: in _what_ way ? Add the table details and what you want to show in your UI - do this by editing your question.

Comment: oh i just saw that you left a article, thanks :)

Comment: ordered by the ascendent order of id_pedido

Comment: @Victor: Maybe it would be better if you read some documentations about SQL queries and how to proceed their results. The explanation by Anand here is really good, but will not have much effect if you just ask questions all time instead of thinking and understanding. Understanding needs time and should not be replaced by "let someone else do everything for me"

Comment: you are right, sorry, i will read the article and try to understand, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Databases produce result sets that are rectangular:

```
SELECT * FROM Person

Name, Age, City
---------------
Joe,  21,  Chicago
Jane, 22,  New York
```

That result set is 2 rows high by 3 columns wide

```
SELECT Name FROM Person

Name
----
Joe
Jane
```

That result set is 2 rows high by 1 column wide

```
SELECT Age, City FROM Person WHERE Name = 'Joe'

Age, City
---------
21,  Chicago
```

That result set is 1 row high by 2 columns wide

`SELECT ...` affects how many columns you get. `WHERE` affects how many rows you get

---

In c#

- `reader.GetString(x)` gets column number `x`
- `reader.Read()` moves on by one row

This means if you want to get 5 columns for 5 textboxes:

```
textBox1.Text = reader.GetString(0);
textBox2.Text = reader.GetString(1);
textBox3.Text = reader.GetString(2);
textBox4.Text = reader.GetString(3);
textBox5.Text = reader.GetString(4);
```

You have to have SELECTed at least 5 columns. You need to have 5 words after your select: `SELECT Name, Age, City, Address, JobTitle FROM person` (Or you need to be `SELECT *`'ing on a table with at least 5 columns)

---

5 textboxes can reasonably show a result set that is 1 row high by 5 columns wide. It doesn't make sense to use textboxes if you have more than one row. The `while(reader.Read())` will loop over every row but you only get the last row data showing in the text boxes

If your result set is 5 rows high by 1 column wide (as your code suggests it might be) you need to Read() repeatedly to move the row on, and always retrieve the first column (there is only one column)

```
textBox1.Text = reader.GetString(0);
reader.Read();

textBox1.Text = reader.GetString(0);
reader.Read();

textBox3.Text = reader.GetString(0);
reader.Read();

textBox4.Text = reader.GetString(0);
reader.Read();

textBox5.Text = reader.GetString(0);
```

Get straight in your mind your rows and your columns. GetString(99) gets the 100th column. Doing reader.Read() 50 times means you're getting the data from the 50th row

Typically in C# we have objects that are related data together - a person object with name, age etc properties. In databases data that is kept together is on the same row. Different rows in a database map to different objects in c#